# NullPointerException - when running very simple test in rest assured

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, rest-assured

I get the following error when trying to run this code:

```
import com.jayway.restassured.response.Response;
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.*;

public class TestRestAssured {
public static void main (String args[]){
// Call the REST service
Response res = get("http://10.213.75.170:5000/bla"); // <--- Crashes on this line.

    // Get the JSON payload
    String json = res.asString();
 }

   }
```

---

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GeneratedMetaMethod$DgmMethodRecord.loadDgmInfo(GeneratedMetaMethod.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.registerMethods(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:155)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:61)
    at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:29)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.createMap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:619)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseParserRegistrar.<init>(ResponseParserRegistrar.groovy)
    at com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.<clinit>(RestAssured.java:336)
    at TestRestAssured.main(TestRestAssured.java:16)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteClassLoader.loadClass(CallSiteClassLoader.java:45)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.loadClass(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:58)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.define(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts$1.run(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts$1.run(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:84)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.defineClassAndGetConstructor(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteGenerator.compilePojoMethod(CallSiteGenerator.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.createPojoMetaMethodSite(CachedMethod.java:257)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.createCachedMethodSite(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:159)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.createPojoMetaMethodSite(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:148)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.createPojoCallSite(MetaClassImpl.java:3015)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createPojoSite(CallSiteArray.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseParserRegistrar.<init>(ResponseParserRegistrar.groovy:42)
    at com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.createTestSpecification(RestAssured.java:1094)
    at com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.given(RestAssured.java:746)
    at com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.get(RestAssured.java:776)
    at TestRestAssured.main(TestRestAssured.java:16)
```

I am using the rest assured 1.7, groovy 1.8.8, all the rest assured dependencies are loaded in my system library path. I am also using jdk 1.7. This is an environmental problem of some sort, as a coworker as no problem running the same code with same .jar files...

Comment: Are you and your co-worker using the same JDK? I've seen Groovy bugs before where it fails on OpenJDK and not on Sun JDK. You could compare vendor and version.

Comment: Line numbers would help. Or a comment like `// <-- crashes on this line`

Comment: Where is your 'get' method defined? Please post it if you want further help.

Comment: Sorry, the import is really unintuitive, please show me how to add the lines on the code... easily. It crashes on line 13, which is: Response res = get("http://10.213.75.170:5000/bla").

Comment: its in the static import: import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.*; You want me to get it out of there ?

Comment: Thanks @Martin Ellis. We are both using Sun JDK.

Comment: http://rest-assured.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/apidocs/index.html?com/jayway/restassured/RestAssured.html: explains getMethod. have not found the code yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your `get` seems to return the `NullPointerException`.

```
at com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.get(RestAssured.java:776)
```

Something is going wrong inside of this method.

You probably missed the third party dependencies as noted in the [instructions](http://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/GettingStarted). It seems like the error pops up when loading the other classes.

> Non-maven users
>
> Download REST Assured and put it in your class-path. You may also need to download the third-party dependencies and put them in your classpath as well.

Comment: per my original question: "all the rest assured dependencies are loaded in my system library path"